# In Docker, can't cd into directory installed with "go get"?

Tags: docker, go, go-modules, go-get

I'm trying to build a Docker container which downloads the source of https://github.com/micromdm/scep and using the `go get` command and `cd`s into the resulting directory in order to perform some follow-up commands (namely, `make deps`, `make build`, and `COPY`ing the relevant resulting binary into the container's `PATH`).

So far I've tried this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:latest
ENV GO111MODULE on
RUN ["go", "get", "github.com/micromdm/scep"]
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/micromdm/scep
```

However, if I try to run this I get the following error:

```
> docker build . --tag loadtest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/4 : FROM golang:latest
 ---> 52b59e9ead8e
Step 2/4 : ENV GO111MODULE on
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 28335bf0142b
Step 3/4 : RUN ["go", "get", "github.com/micromdm/scep"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 86760bf0c490
Step 4/4 : RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/micromdm/scep
 ---> Running in b86fc3ab0ab8
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /go/src/github.com/micromdm/scep
The command '/bin/sh -c cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/micromdm/scep' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

If I try the command without setting the `GO111MODULE` environment variable to `on`, I get his error:

```
> docker build . --tag loadtest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:latest
 ---> 52b59e9ead8e
Step 2/3 : RUN ["go", "get", "github.com/micromdm/scep"]
 ---> Running in 8cb54311a416
package github.com/micromdm/scep: no Go files in /go/src/github.com/micromdm/scep
The command 'go get github.com/micromdm/scep' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Following https://github.com/ponzu-cms/ponzu/issues/204, I also tried running it with a `...` at the end,

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN ["go", "get", "github.com/micromdm/scep/..."]
RUN cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/micromdm/scep \
```

but this results in

```
> docker build . --tag loadtest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:latest
 ---> 52b59e9ead8e
Step 2/3 : RUN ["go", "get", "github.com/micromdm/scep/..."]
 ---> Running in 961bae3bb455
# github.com/micromdm/scep/scep
src/github.com/micromdm/scep/scep/scep.go:318:17: p7.EncryptionAlgorithm undefined (type *pkcs7.PKCS7 has no field or method EncryptionAlgorithm)
src/github.com/micromdm/scep/scep/scep.go:449:26: too many arguments in call to pkcs7.Encrypt
src/github.com/micromdm/scep/scep/scep.go:449:53: undefined: pkcs7.WithEncryptionAlgorithm
src/github.com/micromdm/scep/scep/scep.go:542:26: too many arguments in call to pkcs7.Encrypt
src/github.com/micromdm/scep/scep/scep.go:542:54: undefined: pkcs7.WithEncryptionAlgorithm
The command 'go get github.com/micromdm/scep/...' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Any ideas about how I could achieve downloading the package and `cd`ing into the resulting directory?

Comment: What is the reason you cd into this directory? Any reason you are not defining  WORKDIR?

Comment: `RUN cd ...anything...` doesn't do anything useful (unless it's part of a compound command; `RUN cd ...anything... && do_something_else`, for example, can be useful, since it puts `do_something_else` in the `anything` directory, even though it doesn't change the working directory of a separate/subsequent `RUN`). Each `RUN` command happens inside a new and unique shell that isn't used for anything else, so `cd` -- which changes the state of the *current shell* -- has no lasting effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I am aware that `RUN cd ...` doesn't do anything useful and in its original form this command is paired with `&&` and subsequent commands, I just left it in this simplified form to show only what was needed to reproduce the error message.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, in docker you are building a container, so trying to cd into a directory in your pc its not possible. Use the WORKDIR command, also id recomend to git clone into a repository and there create the Dockerfile, and then COPY everything in there to a directory inside the docker for example:

```
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app/where_you_want_to_cd
RUN whatever_you_want_to_run
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set this path to be your WORKDIR, and the follow up command would be easy.

From the [docker builder reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder), each RUN command is run independently. So doing `RUN cd` does not have any effect on the next RUN command.

The following Dockerfile works:

```
FROM golang:latest

ENV GO111MODULE on
RUN go get github.com/micromdm/scep
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/micromdm/scep
```

You need here the `GO111MODULE` since in the `go.mod` of that module isn't defined the go version, so you need to activate it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the resulting code is located not in `/go/src`, but in `/go/pkg`.